# How do I make it so the last multiplication sign is not included in the line of factorials?

Tags: java

So I need to get rid of this final multiplication sign in each line. I've tried a few different ways but they just messed up my code or didn't work, and I can't seem to wrap my head around how to go about this.

**Here's an example of the output:**

```
Starting value (at least 2): 
59

Ending value (at least 2): 
64

59 = 59 x 

60 = 2 x 2 x 3 x 5 x 

61 = 61 x 

62 = 2 x 31 x 

63 = 3 x 3 x 7 x 

64 = 2 x 2 x 2 x 2 x 2 x 2 x
```

**Here's how I want it to look:**

```
Starting value (at least 2): 
59

Ending value (at least 2): 
64

59 = 59 

60 = 2 x 2 x 3 x 5 

61 = 61 

62 = 2 x 31 

63 = 3 x 3 x 7 

64 = 2 x 2 x 2 x 2 x 2 x 2
```

**And here's the code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrimeFact {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int start, stop;
        int number = 0;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Starting value (at least 2): ");
        start = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Ending value (at least 2): ");
        stop = input.nextInt();

        // stops the program if the user entered n input that cannot be factored
        if (start < 2 || stop < 2) {
            System.out.println("Amount must be at least 2 rather than " + start + " and " + stop + ". Quitting.");
            System.exit(0);
        } // end if

        // loop
        // calls factors
        for (int i = start; i <= stop; i++) {
            number = i;
            printFactors(i);
            System.out.println();
        } // ends loop

    }// ends main

    // prints prime factors
    public static void printFactors(int number) {
        int out = number;
        int count = 0;
        System.out.print(out + " = ");
        for (int factor = 2; factor <= number; factor++) {
            int exponent = 0;
            while (number % factor == 0) {
                number /= factor;
                exponent++;
                count++;
            }
            if (exponent > 0) {
                printExponents(exponent, factor, count);

            }
        }
    }

    //prints the factors the required number of times
    public static void printExponents(int exponent, int factor, int count) {

        for (int q = 1; q <= exponent; q++) {
            System.out.print(factor + " x ");
            // if (q /= count) {
            // System.out.print(factor);
            // }
        }
    }

}// ends class
```

Comment: `System.out.print(factor + (q != exponent ? " x " : ""));`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch did you try that? Looks to me like that would suppress the x after the second 2 in 2x2x3x5. I get what you are trying to do. I am thinking better to build in an x before any factor that is not the very first (since you anticipate the first but not the last).

Comment: @JeremyKahan In my own code, I'd probably use a [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html).

Comment: These are not factorials. They are factors.

Answer (score 0):

into printFactors near the declarations of the ints add in

```
boolean hadFactor = false;
```

also amend your call there to:

```
if (exponent > 0) {
            printExponents(exponent, factor, count, hadFactor);
            hadFactor=true; 

        }
```

and in printExponents do

```
public static void printExponents(int exponent, int factor, int count, boolean hadFactor) {

    for (int q = 1; q <= exponent; q++) {
        if (hadFactor){System.out.print(" x ")}
        System.out.print(factor);
        hadFactor=true;
        // if (q /= count) {
        // System.out.print(factor);
        // }
    }
```